# Hypothesis test: Testing for the median given a set of numbers

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are froma continous distribution and we test whether the median of these observations is 100 against the alternative that the median is greater than 100. Let $Y$ be the number of $X_i$'s greater than 100.

What is the distribution of $Y$ under the null hypothesis and if $n=4832$ and $Y=263$ find the p-value for this test?

For the first part I believe that the distribution of Y is  $Y\sim Bin(n,p=\#greater>100/n)$. And the second part I got

$H_o:median(X_1,..X_n)=100$ vs $H_A: median(X_1,..,X_n)>100$

$Pvalue=P(Y>100)=P(\dfrac{y-482*\frac{263}{482}}{\sqrt{482*\frac{263}{482}\frac{219}{482}}}> \dfrac{100-263}{\sqrt{482*\frac{263}{482}\frac{219}{482}}})=P(Z>\dfrac{-163}{\sqrt{10.9314}})=1$. Would this be a right way of getting the p-value? I think Y follows a binomial under the $H_0$.  I don't think we have use continuity correction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: We are **assuming** that the null hypothesis holds, that is, that  the median is $100$. We want to find out how unlikely is a result of $263$ or more test results $\gt 100$, **under the hypothesis** that the median is $100$. Under that hypothesis, $Y$ has binomial distribution with mean $(482)(1/2)=241$, and variance $(482)(1/4)$. (You are using the wrong $p$ for the binomial.)

The probability that such a binomial has value $\ge 263$ can be computed using the normal approximation to the binomial. Out of general caution, I would use the continuity correction.

Comment: I was thinking that if we have a data set say 100,100,100,100,100 and the median is 100 but the Probability any number is greater than 100 is 0 which is how I came up with the p=#>100/n.

Comment: The distribution is continuous, so the probability any result is exactly $100$ is $0$. By the definition of the median,  if $100$ is the median then the probability an observation is $\gt 100$ is $1/2$.

Comment: Oh thanks for point for that out. I forgot that these numbers come from a continuous distribution.  I assume that my calculation is wrong. Rather it should be $P(Y\geq 263)$ using $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and variance $120.5$.?

Comment: As a ballpark figure, note that the standard deviation $\sqrt{(482)(1/4)}$ is about $11$. And $263$ is about $2$ standard deviation units from the supposed mean of $241$. So the $P$-value will not be far from $0.025$.

Comment: About your previous comment, yes, that is basically what the answer said.